# Is there a formula to find the smallest rectangular prism that will contain different sized rectangular prism?

Tags: python, formula

Have you seen a picture of Amazon truck that contains the shipment at its full capacity?
The boxes are inserted in a way that utilizes every space of the truck.

Here is my question.
The actual number is to help you visualize.
I have three sets of boxes: Box A, Box B, and Box C.
Box A has dimension (D" x E" x F") ~ (About 3" x 4" x 5")
Box B has dimension (G" x H" x I") ~ (About 6" x 7" x 8")
Box C has dimension (J" x K" x L") ~ (About 9" x 10" x 11")

Now, I also have two large crates Crate M and Crate N.
Crate M has dimension (O" x P" x Q") ~ (About 30" x 31" x 32")
Crate N has dimension (R" x S" x T") ~ (About 33" x 34" x 35")

I want to ship 20 sets of Box A, Box B, and Box C.
Should I use Crate M or Crate N?
I want to waste less space, so I want to use the smaller crate as long as everything fits inside.

This seems related to the minimum bound box algorithm, but I'm having a hard time.
How should I approach this question?

Answer (score 1):

there's no algorithm for now for optimal packing. most of the shipping companies use simulation to my knowledge.
so basically container has dimensions of (X,Y,Z) so you need to pack your crates in a orientation and in an order that satisfies this rule
ratio X/(packed place x), Y/(packed place y), Z/(packed place z) is more or less the same. so you need an algorithm that will try each packing order and calculate this ratio.
this is because you are with no place left, thus optimally packed, when packed place dimensions and container dimensions are the same. so you are being optimal while your packed dimensions is scalar of container dimensions.
it takes N! operations to calculate best fit

here is small algorithm that would help you with this.

```
import numpy as np 

def compare_two_packing(a,b,c):
    _box_x=c[0]/np.sqrt(c[1]**2+c[2]**2)
    _box_y=c[1]/np.sqrt(c[0]**2+c[2]**2)
    _box_z=c[2]/np.sqrt(c[1]**2+c[0]**2)
    _first_package_x=a[0]/np.sqrt(a[1]**2+a[2]**2)
    _first_package_y=a[1]/np.sqrt(a[0]**2+a[2]**2)
    _first_package_z=a[2]/np.sqrt(a[1]**2+a[0]**2)
    _second_package_x=b[0]/np.sqrt(b[1]**2+b[2]**2)
    _second_package_y=b[1]/np.sqrt(b[0]**2+b[2]**2)
    _second_package_z=b[2]/np.sqrt(b[1]**2+b[0]**2)
    diagonal_1=(_box_x-_first_package_x)**2+(_box_y-_first_package_y)**2+(_box_z-_first_package_z)**2
    diagonal_2=(_box_x-_second_package_x)**2+(_box_y-_second_package_y)**2+(_box_z-_second_package_z)**2
    if(diagonal_1<diagonal_2):
        return(True)
    else:
        return(False)
        
_crate_dimensions=[a,b,c]
_first_package=[x,y,z]
_second_package=[i,j,k]

if(compare_two_packing(_first_package,_second_package,_crate_dimensions)):
    print("first packaging is optimal")
else:
    print("second packaging is optimal")
```